# Unable to create tirex gdal datasource for OpenTopoMap

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, dem, tile-server

I try to set up an OSM tile server using tirex on a server running Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS 64-bit.
In the style definition (opentopomap.xml) there are several gdal data sources definied. E.g. the following color relief layer:

```
<Layer name="relief-5000">
<StyleName>relief-5000</StyleName>
<Datasource>
    <Parameter name="type">gdal</Parameter>
    <Parameter name="file">dem/relief-5000.tif</Parameter>
    <Parameter name="format">tiff</Parameter>
</Datasource>
```

At the relative path to the style-file (dem/relief-5000.tif) I have the tiff file with the following access rights:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 8866 Feb  5 01:29 relief-5000.tif*
```

My tirex user is in the postgres group and should be able to read the layer's file

```
uid=112(tirex) gid=119(tirex) groups=119(tirex),118(postgres)
```

But when I start tirex and check /var/log/daemon.log I get the following error message:

```
Feb  5 10:27:23 ubuntu-server tirex-backend-mapnik[4739]: 
Renderer started (name=mapnik)

Feb  5 10:27:23 ubuntu-server tirex-backend-mapnik[4739]: 
cannot add /etc/tirex/renderer/mapnik/opentopomap.conf

Feb  5 10:27:23 ubuntu-server tirex-backend-mapnik[4739]: 
Could not create datasource for type: 'gdal' 
(no datasource plugin directories have been successfully registered)  
encountered during parsing of layer 'relief-5000' in Layer at line 24 of 
'/usr/share/osm-styles/OpenTopoMap/mapnik/opentopomap.xml'
```

I have installed the packages gdal-bin python-gdal libgdal-dev. Is there any special configuration for gdal datasources required or a possibility to get more fine grained log-messages to estimate the reason, why this datasource file cannot be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further investigation of this issue I found the solution: Mapnik's data sources weren't recognized at all.

Workaround:
in

```
/etc/tirex/renderer/mapnik.conf
```

change:

```
plugindir=/usr/lib/mapnik/3.0/input # mapnik-config --input-plugins
```

Comment: Thank you, my installation didn't have the `3.0` version in the path.